# NumPy loadtext()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a text file which I want to load into a `NumPy` array with `loadtext()`. The file is tab delimited and sometime I have a value after the last tab instead of empty:

```
Value1\tab\Value2\tab\value3\tab
Value4\tab\Value5\tab\value6\tab\value7
Value8\tab\Value9\tab\value10\tab
Value11\tab\Value12\tab\value13\tab
```

However, `NumPy` gives me an error with that line:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of columns
```

**Is it possible to load such a data structure directly into a `NumPy` array (with `None` as a value)?** Or do I have to open the file, insert a `None` if there is no value and load the manipulated text file in a `NumPy` array?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly an answer but more of a suggestion: you could load your data into a 2D list with `csv`, parse through its lines to append a `None` when it’s too short and then convert the list to a `numpy.array` using the constructor.

Comment: This is what I am doing but I hoped for an easier way. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neither `numpy.genfromtxt` or `numpy.loadtxt` can deal with an uneven number of columns in a file. If you have access to [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/), it can do what you need with [`pandas.read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('myfile.txt',header=None,sep='\t')

# to get the data in a numpy ndarray:
myarray = df.values
```

By default missing values are assigned `NaN`, but you can change that with `df.fillna(value)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.genfromtxt`:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.genfromtxt("myfile.txt", delimiter="\t")
```